# Detecting scroll in Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, iscroll

I can't detect whether the page is scrolled or not with jquery mobile. `Scrolltop` always return 0 in any case.

```
    <script>


        var interval = setInterval(function() {

                                   alert($("#articlecontent").scrollTop());
                                   //alert($(window).scrollTop());
                                   //alert($("#maindiv").scrollTop());

                                   }
                                   }, 3000);

    </script>



    <div data-role="page" id="maindiv">
        <div  class="ui-bar ui-bar-b">


        </div>


        <div id='articlecontent' data-role="content" data-iscroll>

          sldfjlkjsl lksjd kls df hjks djkh sdjfkh sjkf 
          jksd jkhsdf jkhsd hjwiuhhfg skd jkshd fkj fkjsg kjhsdkjf 

          sldfjlkjsl lksjd kls df hjks djkh sdjfkh sjkf 
          jksd jkhsdf jkhsd hjwiuhhfg skd jkshd fkj fkjsg kjhsdkjf 


          sldfjlkjsl lksjd kls df hjks djkh sdjfkh sjkf 
          jksd jkhsdf jkhsd hjwiuhhfg skd jkshd fkj fkjsg kjhsdkjf 



        </div>
        <div data-role="footer" data-id="foo1">


        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

scrollTop() returns a value greater than zero only when there's scrollbar for that element. In this case, you can test by setting the height of the article div to something smaller than the content and force it to show scrollbar. After that try the below code and scroll to see the value changing as you scroll.

```
$("#articlecontent").scroll(function(){ console.log($(this).scrollTop()); });
```